# Python com error (-2147352562: 'Invalid number of parameters.\r\n')

Tags: python, vba, ms-access, macros, win32com

I was digging in the help, through many websites. I seems that there is no solution to the question. Therefore I ask again.

I was trying to call a (public) function that needs three parameters. I see that I successfully connect to the database in access

```
import win32com.client
acApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Access.Application')
acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase('C:/Access_Databases/MyDatabase.accdb')        
acApp.Run("MyProject.ImportingRoutine", Date, LocalPath, Adtnl)
```

After the last line, I get:

"result = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes)  +args)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352562), None)"

Notes: The parameters are a date in format YYYYMMDD (int64), the path is a string to a local repository, "C:/...", yes using "/", the VBA-macro translates into "\" if necessary, and the last is a Boolean parameter (But I provide 0 or -1 for False and True). The same code works nice if I call it from vba-excel.

The com error -2147352562 is about an incorrect number of parameters (why?). 
It seems that Python is unable to run Microsoft Access VBA macro (function) with parameters.

I will code in Python the update that the macro in VBA performs, but I would like to know if I am doing something wrong.

```
Public Function ImportingRoutine(ByVal InDate As Long, _ 
                                 ByVal InPath As String, _
                                 ByVal AddDate As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim FileExists As Boolean
    Dim outIDAV As Variant
    Dim lgSpcDt As Long

    InPath = VBA.Replace(InPath, "/", "\")

    outIDAV = ImportDailyAnalyticVector(InDate, InPath, , True, True, AddDate)

    FileExists = outIDAV(1)
    lgSpcDt = outIDAV(2)


    If FileExists Then
        Call ReadingFieldNames("tblDAVector", "tblMetDat_AVFields")
        Call ChangeAllFieldsType("tblDAVector", "tblMetDat_AVFields", _
                "NewName", "Type", "Order", "Size", "'*CSP','1ESP','1E'", _ 
                 "Vect_Date", lgSpcDt)
        Call ClearingHist
        Call AppendDAtoHist
    End If

    ImportingRoutine = FileExists

End Function
```

That is the function that I am calling.

The headers of the other functions are:

```
Public Function ImportDailyAnalyticVector(ByVal DateDbl As Long, _
                  Path As String, _
                  Optional VectName As String = "VectorAnaliticoYYYYMMDD", _
                  Optional ByVal Zipped As Boolean = False, _ 
                  Optional ByVal Silent As Boolean = True, _
                  Optional ByVal AddDate As Boolean = False) As Variant

Public Function ReadingFieldNames(ByVal tblTarget As String, _
                       ByVal tblFieldNames As String)

Public Function ChangeAllFieldsType(tblTarget As String, _
                        tblAuxiliar As String, _
                        fldName As String, _
                        fldType As String, _
                        fldOrder As String, _
                        fldSize As String, _
                        Optional ExVT As Variant = "''", _
                        Optional NM_Bussiness_Dt As String = "Vect_Date", _
                        Optional New_Date As Long = 0)
```

The last two functions are parameter free. Originally, I designed the database thinking that I will eventually migrate it to SAS system. But given the small budget of my department I decided to learn Python on early February. I discard SAS option, given the (unexpected) advantages that I found in Python. The variables in the DB are quite standard only underscore "_" as special characters are being used.

By the way, I made the following function:

```
Sub ss()
    Call ImportingRoutine(20160908, _
         "C:/Asset_Controlling/Repository/PIP/Vectores_Analiticos/2016/", 0)
End Sub
```

Then I tried to call:

```
acApp.Run("MyProject.ss")
```

But this one also yields the same com error. It is quite easy to know that Python reaches the VBA code. If I try to run:

```
acApp.Run("MyProject.ss()")
```

The new error reads:
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, "Microsoft Access cannot find the procedure 'MyProject.ss().'", None, -1, -2146825771), None)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the VBA function signature...

Comment: Please show the VBA function you are trying to run and show the assignments to the args in Python: *Date*, *LocalPath*, *Adtn1*. Data types must align between languages. This also helps us reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks Parfai, I made several test. I even tried the direct parameters like: acApp.Run("MyProject.ImportingRoutine", 20160908, 
         "C:/Asset_Controlling/Repository/PIP/Vectores_Analiticos/2016/", 0). And simple trial with a zero parameter function, as I showed above.

Comment: Not (yet) sure if it is relevant, but it wouldn't hurt to [edit] your question to indicate the version and bit-ness of Python that you are using.

Comment: Just FYI, I fooled around with `win32com` under CPython 2.7.11 and wasn't having any luck using `Application.Run` (for a `Sub` with or without parameters), but [this code](http://pastebin.com/MdqrzsXT) works just fine under [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/).

Comment: Thanks Gord, Bit-ness I am running 64 bits 3.5.2 Python under Anaconda distribution. The OS is windows 7 professional 64bits, and the Microsoft Office 2013 professional is at 32 bits. Is the bit-ness of MS-Office the weak link?

Comment: *"Is the bit-ness of MS-Office the weak link?"* - It's hard to say. Normally one would expect to have the bit-ness of the Python environment match the bit-ness of the installed version of Office. However, I had no success in getting `win32com` to play nicely with Access COM automation when everything was 32-bit (including Windows).

Comment: `ChangeAllFieldsType`: [Replace the long parameter list with a parameter object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject); an object or structure with data members representing the arguments to be passed in.